# Making a generalised CSV COPY script in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm using the below Python script to COPY a CSV file to one of my PostgreSQL database table.***The script below is working fine,But i'm thinking of making this script a generalised one***,So i need your recommendations/suggestions on how to do this.

**What the script do:**

1) The script will search for a CSV file with name ufl.csv from a specific path and copy its content to a predefined table in PostgreSQL database.

2) Move the CSV file to a new destination once the COPY is done.

**What i want to achieve:**

1) instead of predefining a file name such as ufl.csv , want to take the file which is in the working folder (Or al files if possible).

2)I have predefined the table structure now (The CSV has 75 columns, also *i can download the CSV files in 3 different formats each formats with different column numbers and names*, I want to make it a generalised one so that no matter how many columns or what the column names, it should port the CSV data to a dynamically created PostgreSQL table.

**Please find the below script,**

```
import csv
import psycopg2
import time
import os
from datetime import datetime
import shutil
from time import gmtime, strftime

# File path.
filePath='''/Users/local/Downloads/ufl.csv'''
dirName = '/Users/local/Downloads/ufl_old_files/'

try:
  conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", database="postgres", user="postgres",
                         password="postgres", port="5432")
  print('DB connected')

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        # Confirm unsuccessful connection and stop program execution.
        print ("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)
        print("Database connection unsuccessful.")
        quit()

# Check if the CSV file exists.
#if os.path.isfile(filePath):
 #try:
     #print('Entered loop')   
     #sql = "COPY %s FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER AS ';'  csv header"
     #file = open(filePath, "r" , encoding="latin-1")
     #table = 'stage.ufl_details'# The table structure is already defined.

if os.path.isfile(filePath):
 try:
     print('Entered loop')   
     #sql = "COPY %s FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER AS ';'  csv header"
     sql = "COPY %s FROM PROGRAM 'cat /Users/local/Downloads/*' WITH DELIMITER AS ';'  csv header"
     file = open(filePath, "r" , encoding="latin-1")
     table = 'stage.ufl_details'


     with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("truncate " + table + ";")
        print('truncated the table')
        cur.copy_expert(sql=sql % table, file=file)
        print('Data loaded')
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()

 except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print ("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)
        print("Error adding  information.")
        quit()
#Move the processed CSV file to the new path after renaming it.    

 os.rename(filePath,dirName + 'ufl_old_'+ strftime("%Y_%m_%d", gmtime())+'.csv')

else:
    # Message stating CSV file could not be located.
    print("Could not locate the CSV file.")
    quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `FROM PROGRAM` option of `COPY`

```
COPY tablename FROM PROGRAM 
     'cat /Users/local/Downloads/ufl_old_files/*'  WITH DELIMITER AS ';'  csv header
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the swift response, Will check this and update here.

Comment: Getting error Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL missing data for column "identcode"
CONTEXT:  COPY ufl_details, line 2: ""

Error adding  information....Updated the modification above as you mentioned.Is that what you meant?

Comment: Also the dynamic table creation also can be done or any suggestions on that? It will be of great help.

Comment: @Linu : Is the directory and files present in the client's storage or the server's?

Comment: It is present in server.